# Maximum possible combinations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

Excuse-me if that is very simple. Let's assume we're creating lottery tickets. Each ticket is 5 numbers from 1 to 69 and the goal is making tickets that are unique in a way that no pairs of numbers are repeated.
Ex. Ticket One 1,2,3,4,5
Any pair of these numbers should never be repeated again, But each single number will be paired with other numbers. Ex. Ticket Two 1,6,7,8,9

What's the maximum possible tickets? And what the rule used to calculate?

Comment: Take the total number of pairs and divide by the number of pairs per ticket to get an upper bound.

Comment: Would you please explain more. Two unique pairs from 1 to 69 would be 2346 (68+67+66...+1) and pairs per ticket would be 9 (1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-3, 2-4 ....) 2346/9 is 260.66 correct? But shouldn't the result be a real number?

Comment: I mean the result is supposed to be a whole number. I guess

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To help us help you, we really need to know more than what you've told us. What have you already attempted? We assume you've tried at least *something* before asking for help. Other than what you've tried, what do you know about combinatorics in general that would help you with this problem?

Comment: As a quick start though, consider this: how many tickets must have the number $1$ on them?  A second starting point: consider a toy system with only $7$ numbers, and three numbers to a ticket.

Comment: I know a little about Combinators except C(n,r) The odds are 11238513 (I believe). However, that's different as I'm looking for tickets with no repeat of pairs. I failed to get any clue for a specific rule, so I wrote a simple code, but results weren't the same and ranged from 167 to 173 tickets